# how do I refresh specific div with countdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

I have countdown in my `.container2` div but when I tried to reload that specific container its reload perfectly but my countdown didn't showed up and also button got disabled..

```
<div id="container2">
        <h4 id="title">Type Data here</h4>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="main-controls">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button
                        class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" 
                        data-bs-toggle="dropdown"  id="btnCounter" disabled >
                        File <span id="count"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <button id="txt-btn" class="dropdown-item" onclick="refreshDiv();">
                            Save 
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

```
      var spn = document.getElementById("count");
      var btn = document.getElementById("btnCounter");

       var count = 3; // Set count
        var timer = null; // For referencing the timer

            (function countDown() {
              // Display counter and start counting down
               spn.textContent = count;

            // Run the function again every second if the count is not zero
              if (count !== 0) {
            timer = setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
          count--; // decrease the timer
          } else {
        // Enable the button
          btn.removeAttribute("disabled");
          }
         }());
```

```
             function refreshDiv() {
               $('#container2').load(window.location.href + " #container2");
                }
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what is going on. Why are you trying to reload the container element, and why container3 when the HTML has a container2 and what is spn?

Comment: @A Haworth
check now

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, but I still don't understand why you are wanting to reload code (as opposed to resetting variable(s).

Comment: because I want to start countdown again whenever button click @
A Haworth

Comment: So why not just reset the count (making it a global)?

Comment: actually I am new I don't know how to that I asked this question many times but didn't find any answer I tried for 18 days can u please help @
A Haworth

Comment: Before altering your code I wonder if I am understanding what you want to do properly. Are you just trying to reset the counter (to 3 in your example)? I am confused by the fact that the button is labelled 'save'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `countDown()` function only init time that's the issue. on button click call again `countDown()` function !

Try this code it's help you

```
var count = 3;     // Set count
var timer = null; // For referencing the timer

function countDown() {
  // Display counter and start counting down
  console.log(document.getElementById("count"), 'count');
  document.getElementById("count").textContent = count;

  // Run the function again every second if the count is not zero
  if (count !== 0) {
    timer = setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
    count--; // decrease the timer
  } else {
    // Enable the button
    document.getElementById("btnCounter").removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
}

countDown();

function refreshDiv() {
  $('#container2').load(location.href + " #container2");
  document.getElementById("btnCounter").setAttribute("disabled", true);
  count = 3;

  setTimeout(() => { 
    countDown();
  }, 10); // set page reload time  in timeout
}
```

Comment: brother thank you.. its working its even better if you refresh that div also :) @MayurVaghasiya

Comment: When `refreshDiv()` function call div  also refresh pls check !

Comment: yeah I checked its reload but countdown didn't showed @Mayur Vaghasiya

Comment: yeah I checked its reload but countdown didn't showed

Comment: brother I tried your code its work perfectly but when I click that button its reload perfect and also countdown work perfectly but why my another `container` div showed up ? can you help @Mayur Vaghasiya

Comment: @himasnhu I update my answer ! that's works perfectly ! check

Comment: now container not reloading .

Comment: how do you check ? container load or not

Comment: container not load @Mayur Vaghasiya

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241298/discussion-between-mayur-vaghasiya-and-himasnhu).

Answer (score 1):

what are you trying to do? is it something like this?
when reload button is pressed, reload div also function inside div? so countdown function execute again?

hope this help, and give you clue.

```js
var spn = $("#count")
var btn = $("#btnCounter")
var myInterval
var count = 3 // Set count
var timer = null


// set interval without delay
function setIntervalImmediately(func, interval) {
    func();
    return setInterval(func, interval);
}



function countDown(sec){
        myInterval = setIntervalImmediately(function () {
            $('#count').text(sec--);
            if (sec == -1) {
                clearInterval(myInterval);
                    $('#count').text("");
                btn.removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            else{
                     btn.attr("disabled", "disabled")
            }
    }, 1000);
}

$(document).on("click", "#txt-btn", function(){
  clearInterval(myInterval);
    refreshDiv()
})

function refreshDiv(){
    $("#container2").load(location.href + " #container2");
  countDown(count)
}

$(document).ready(function(){
        countDown(count)
})
```

```html
<div id="container2">
        <h4 id="title">Type Data here</h4>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="main-controls">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" id="btnCounter" disabled>
                        File <span id="count"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <button id="txt-btn" class="dropdown-item">
                            Save? do u mean reload?
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes its fine but why button won't disabled after reloading ? @krystallix

Comment: oh, fixed it just now. @himasnhu

Comment: yes its perfect now but after reload my countdown goes in minus like this -3 and also button won't enable

Comment: see in your snippet time goes -minus @krystallix

Comment: oh really? mine not showing any error. so I don't understand what u do mean  goes minus. check my [screen record](https://giphy.com/gifs/omcfFc996p7cHFZdWz)

Comment: no its showing please check again click 2 time in save button @krystallix

Comment: You have solved so much, just do it a little @krystallix

Comment: did You solve ?

Comment: yeah, I forgot clear interval after click, and I also add function that remove delay after click reload button.

Comment: why my code is not working @krystallix

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241296/discussion-between-himasnhu-and-krystallix).